# Relationship between HttpClient, HttpConnection and ClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

Lets consider one of the latest (4.2.x) releases of HttpComponents.

Please explain how generally an instance of `HttpClient` is related to instance of `HttpConnection` (such as `ManagedClientConnectionImpl`) and also `ClientConnectionManager`.
Who knows about who ?

I will refer to them below ommiting [Http] prefix. So, `HttpClient` -> `Client`

I understand that `Client` keeps reference to `ClientConnectionManager`. 
Does that mean that `Client` also has reference to underlying `Connection` object ?

Does `ConnectionManager` knows about all `Clients` linked to it ?

How `HttpGet`, which is used by HttpClient to perform `execute`, knows about stream, exposed thru response's `Entity` ? (which it does, because we can close the stream by calling `.abort()` on `HttpGet` object.) Is `HttpGet` instance also linked to `Connection` object ?

I am confused and would appreciate detailed overview answering the questions above. To give examples, you could use any specific implementations, such as `DefaultHttpClient`, `ManagedClientConnectionImpl`, `BasicClientConnectionManager`, if it would make understanding easier.

Comment: The HttpGet doesn't know about stream. The HttpClient does (or manager) does. It uses the data inside HttpGet to generate a Get HTTP request. Download the source code and step through it with a debugger.

Comment: @Sotirios Thanks for advice, can't debug it in detail now, but if I don't get any answers I will have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpClient` is a facade to the request execution pipeline. The exact composition of the execution pipeline depends on the configuration of the `HttpClient` instance. Think of it as a browser with multiple tabs.

One of more `HttpClient` instances can depend on one `ClientConnectionManager` sharing the underlying pool of persistent connections. `ClientConnectionManager` instances have no knowledge of `HttpClient` instances that depend upon them. They just lease connections to whatever entity requests them.

Each request is executed within a particular `HttpContext`. `HttpContext` instance is a collection of all stateful objects involved in execution of the actual HTTP exchange. `HttpContext` instances are not thread-safe and may not be shared by multiple worker threads.

When initiating an HTTP exchange `HttpClient` leases a `ManagedClientConnection` instance from the `ClientConnectionManager` it is associated with. It serializes and transmits the request message to the opposite endpoint, receives a response head, and binds the underlying connection to the response `HttpEntity` instance (when available) without reading the response content. This enables the consumer of HttpResponse instance stream the response content without intermediate in-memory buffering. This also makes it necessary for the consumer to ensure proper release of resources (in particular `ManagedClientConnection`) associated with the response.

Comment: Thanks, things become clearer now. So the `HttpResponse` knows about undrlyuing connection (via `Entity`). How about `HttpGet` ? Does it also become aware of underlying connection after `HttpClient` performes `execute` on it ? I suppose it should know about connection, because when we call `abort()` on `HttpGet` it also closes the stream if it is open, right ?

Comment: AbortableHttpRequest interface provides an injection point for  connection lease operation as well connection release trigger. This enables all methods that implement this interface to abort request execution at any point and release the underlying connection.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I would like to look at implementation to see how this injection is done. Or may be you could append a snapshot of code to your answer ? BTW, are you Oleg Kalnichevski, a HttpComponents developer (just curious)?

Comment: There is nothing special about it, just a trivial setter injection. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-dev/httpclient/xref/org/apache/http/impl/execchain/MainClientExec.html#153

Comment: Would you be able to fill in additional context about the related timeouts - "http.connection.timeout" and "http.conn-manager.timeout"? Based on your response, it would seem like the "conn-manager" timeout applies when the HttpClient is waiting for a lease. What about "http.connection.timeout"? Does it time the manager when waiting to create a connection, or the client when using a connection that it has leased? Thanks for any help